# SQL Joining two fields in one table to one in another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT        
    Users.[First Name], Users.[User ID], Users.Login, 
    Users.Surname, Users.Password, Users.[Account Question], 
    Users.[Account Answer], Users.[Region Access], Users.[Account Access], 
    Users.owningsite, Users.Currentsitesetting, Users.createdby, 
    Users.createddate, Users.lastmodby, Users.lastmoddate, Users.active, 
    Sites.Sitename    
FROM
    Users 
INNER JOIN 
    Sites ON Users.owningsite = Sites.SiteID AND Users.Currentsitesetting = Sites.SiteID    
WHERE
    (Users.owningsite = 1)
```

Now I need two bound fields containing ID Numbers (Owningsite & currentsitesetting) to connect site name and provide sitename's depending on the ID Numbers for both for a user form so instead instead of display 1,2 it displays Site A, Site B.

Is the SQL wrong or am I missing something in the ASPX markup?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="First_Name" 
    SortExpression="First_Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" 
    SortExpression="Surname" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Login" HeaderText="Login" SortExpression="Login" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" 
    SortExpression="Password" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Account_Question" HeaderText="Account_Question" 
    SortExpression="Account_Question" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Account_Answer" HeaderText="Account_Answer" 
    SortExpression="Account_Answer" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Region_Access" HeaderText="Region_Access" 
    SortExpression="Region_Access" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Account_Access" HeaderText="Account_Access" 
    SortExpression="Account_Access" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="sitename" HeaderText="owningsite" 
    SortExpression="sitename" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="sitename" HeaderText="Currentsitesetting" 
    SortExpression="sitename" />
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="active" HeaderText="active" 
    SortExpression="active" />
```

Comment: I am not sure, but is it allowed to have same DataField and SortExpression for both "owningsite" and "Currentsitesetting"?

Comment: "is the SQL wrong or am I missing something in the ASP?" Well does the SQL query return what you want it to in SSMS? That will answer that.

Comment: it seems to return only the first joined field not the second

Comment: Dmitri, I know that bit wont work but I put it in there to illustrate what I want to be there

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I got it correctly, you need to display a string **Site A** or **Site B** based on OwningSite and CurrentSiteSetting. You need a template column (TemplateField) in order to write down the logic which transforms the real column value to a template value. Something like the following asp.net script (using C#):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site Name (owning)">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("owningsite") == 1 ? "Site A" : "Site B" %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site Name (setting)">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Currentsitesetting") == 1 ? "Site A" : "Site B" %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

try to replace the following part of your asp.net with the previous sample.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="sitename" HeaderText="owningsite" 
  SortExpression="sitename" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="sitename" HeaderText="Currentsitesetting" 
  SortExpression="sitename" />
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not quite what I am after, in the sites table is a list of site names with ID numbers. in the users table each user has a site id for whos site that particular person belongs to and another for what site access they are currently set to, example being a regional manager has access to 3 sites but is based at site 1. so I need to get the site name based on owning site id number and then again for the current site ID

Comment: About asp.net I guess it works. About SQL syntax, you have to do two joins, one on owningsite and one on Currentsitesetting. Using two joins will give you two links (one for each site).

Comment: do you mean two separate joins, rather the one join with AND in like above ?

Comment: Yes, have you tried two joins on sites table? The first on owningsite and the second on currentsitesetting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok This works to get the two fields connected however its showing weird results, ie getting multiple records for the same person for each sitename in the table

```
SELECT        
Users.[First Name], Users.[User ID], Users.Login, Users.Surname, Users.Password, 
Users.[Account Question], Users.[Account Answer], Users.[Region Access], 
Users.[Account Access], Users.owningsite, Users.Currentsitesetting, Users.createdby, 
Users.createddate, Users.lastmodby, Users.lastmoddate, Users.active, 
Sites.Sitename AS owningsitename, Sites_1.Sitename AS Currentsitename

FROM             Users 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Sites ON Users.owningsite = Sites.SiteID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Sites AS Sites_1 ON Users.Currentsitesetting = Sites.SiteID

WHERE        (Users.owningsite = 1)
```

Comment: In this case I suggest you to post the `CREATE TABLE` of the objects you need, then some `INSERT` sample data and the **expected results** based on the schema you've created. You can use also [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)